# change link color, adjust font size and remove "powered by" links inside cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, livechat

I wish to change link color, adjust font size and even completely remove it. If you may, please visit the tawk.to website and in the lower right corner you'll see the link back that resides inside of iframe(s).

```
<div id="bottomContainer"><a id="tawktoLink" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">©&nbsp;tawk.to</a></div>
```

I tried using CSS but that failed misserably and even attempted using a small script like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    ('#tawkchat-iframe-container').contents().find('#bottomContainer').hide();
});
</script>
```

Many live chat services display a link, specifically, apps like:

- 1click
- bubbles
- clickdesk
- live2support
- heybubble
- intercom
- liveagen
- livechat
- livezilla
- olar
- zopim
- tawk.to

Comment: You cannot change the contents of a cross-domain iframe. What you are attempting to do is not possible. I would also imagine this is illegal as removing the watermark is likely a breach of their service terms and conditions.

Comment: thanks for the clarity and heads up. for some reason, i was under the impression i could control the content being delivered from another iframe on an external domain. weird.